# How to sketch the graph of $\sin(x^2)$?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

Clearly, we see that $y = \sin(x^2)$ is not periodic as $0$, $\sqrt{\pi}$, $\sqrt{2\pi}$, etc. are not equally spaced and for each of these values, $y=0$.

Also $x^2$ changes much faster than $x$ does (w.r.t. slope)

But I don't understand how to sketch it.

Comment: You could plot the points where $x^2$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ and then sketch in a cramped sine curve in each interval between them.

Comment: One way to think of this is that $sin(x^2)=sin(x\cdot x)$, so it's a sine curve with a frequency of $x$, i.e. as $x$ increases, the sine keeps getting faster (and more bunched together). (Also, I think 'graphing-functions would be a better tag for your question, since confusingly enough, 'graph theory' means something totally different.)

Comment: Notice that $\sin(x^2)$ is even so you can ignore negative values. Also the distance between the roots tends to zero as $x$ becomes large so expect a squashed sine curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still has a wavy shape, but that wave becomes more and more "smooshed" together as $x$ tends to $\pm\infty$. For $x\ge0$, let $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\sin(x^2)$. Notice that for $a\ge0$, the function $f$ can be described as the set of points $(a,\sin a)$, and $g$ as the set of points $(\sqrt{a},\sin a)$. So, in theory, you could plot the graph of $g$ by taking the graph of $f$, and then shifting all the $x$-coordinates to their square roots while keeping the $y-$coordinates the same. This explains why $0,\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{2\pi},\dots$ are all roots of $g$.

To investigate the "smooshing" effects further, suppose that the points $\mathrm{P}(a,\sin a)$ and $\mathrm{Q}(b,\sin b)$ both lie on the graph of $f$. Then, the corresponding points on the graph of $g$ are $\mathrm{P'}(\sqrt{a},\sin a)$ and $\mathrm{Q'}(\sqrt{b},\sin b)$. The horizontal distance between $P$ and $Q$ is $|b-a|$, whereas the horizontal distance between $\mathrm{P'}$ and $\mathrm{Q'}$ is $|\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}|$. Hence, the horizontal distance has been shrunk by a factor of
$$
\frac{|b-a|}{\left|\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}\right|}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} \, .
$$
Hence, increasing either $a$ or $b$ magnifies the compression effect that can be readily seen in the graph below. This also provides a visual explanation for why the graph appears to get steeper and steeper as $x\to\infty$. Consideration of the derivative $g'(x)=2x\cos(x^2)$ confirms this.

[image: sin x]

[image: sin(x^2)]

[image: both]

(It should be easy to fill in the details for what happens for $x<0$ because $g$ is even.)

Comment: Isn't $g$ even?

Comment: @user: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It might also be interesting to note the behavior near $x=0$, which you could expect based on the first term of the Maclaurin (Taylor) series for $g$ being $x^2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Good point! So I suppose you could say (in a hand-wavey sense) that $\sin(x^2)$ is "locally" parabolic around $x=0$.